# How to prove a set is a star domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $0<r<R$, and consider the following sets:

$$G_1=\{\rho\exp(i\alpha)\,:\, r\lt \rho \lt R\,,\,0\lt \alpha\lt 2\pi\}\,,$$

and
$$G_1=\{\rho\exp(i\alpha)\,:\, r\lt \rho \lt R\,,\,0\le \alpha\lt 2\pi\}\,.$$

How can I prove these two sets are star domins or not?

Comment: Those are both annuli (well $G_1$ is an annulus minus a ray). They don't have any chance to be star-domains.

Answer (score 2):

Both are rings (the first one with a slit). For any point consider the 'opposite' point; they can not be connected with a straight line inside $G_1$ or $G_2.$ So no point can be the star center.